# How to send message attributes along with message body on AWS sqs using Camel?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-camel, amazon-sqs

i want to send some message attributes to AWS sqs along with message body using camel routes. But only message body is getting sent. I am unable to send message attributes to SQS.Below is my route

```
from("direct:send-to-sqs")
                .setBody(simple("${exchangeProperty.ENTITY_JSON}"))
                .setProperty("systemName",simple("FINANCE"))
                .log("body which is to be send to sqs is ${body}")
                .to("aws-sqs://{my sqs url}:QueueForPOC?" +
                        "amazonSQSClient=#sqsClient&attributeNames=#systemName")
                .log("entity has been sent to SQS.");
```

Can anyone please give me some clue and help??

Comment: Try to use `setHeader` instead of `setProperty`

Comment: @Greenev Thank you so much bro...it worked for me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `setHeader` instead of `setProperty`